# Find if numeric character in PHP String

Tags: php, preg-match, numeric

Sorry for asking this simple question, but I seem not to find any answers.

How can you check whether there is a number within a string?

I've tried:

```
    $string = "this is a simple string with a number 2432344";
    if (preg_match('/[^0-9]/', "$string")) {
        echo "yes a number";
    } else {
        echo "no number";
    }
```

Doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to find a number, don't negate the character set with `^` in your regular expression. That means "match anything *except* a number".

```
$string = "this is a simple string with a number 2432344";

if (preg_match('/[0-9]/', "$string")) {
    echo "yes a number";
} else {
    echo "no number";
}
```

Also, you could just use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`, and `$string` instead of `"$string"`.

Answer (score 0):

`^` will only negate what's in the regex. You don't need to use it.

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong. A `^` at the start of a character set negates the character set; it's not an anchor. (See sentence #1 `:)`)